# How do online judge sites isolate program performance?

Tags: performance, isolation

There are many online judge sites which can verify your program by comparing its output to the correct answers. What's more, they also check the running time to make sure that your program running time doesn't exceed the maximum limit.

So here is my question, since some online judge sites run several test programs at the same time, how do they achieve performance isolation, i.e., how can they make sure that a user program running in a heavy-loaded environment will finish within the same time, as when it is running in an idle environment?

Comment: They might use more than one server to run the tests.

Comment: What are some sites which do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Operating systems keep track of CPU time separately from real-world "wall clock" time. It's very common when benchmarking to only look at one or the other kind of time. CPU or file I/O intensive tasks can be measured with just CPU time. Tasks that require external resources, like querying a remote database, are best measured in wall clock time because you don't have access to the CPU time on the remote resource.

If a judging site is just comparing CPU times of different tests, the site can run many tests simultaneously. On the other hand, if wall clock times matter, then the site must either use independent hardware or a job queue that ensures one test finishes before the next starts.

Comment: As to comparing CPU times, it is still unfair to run many tests simultaneously. Since some resources like CPU cache and TLB available to programs will become much less in multi-tests environment, which may have great impacts on program performance.

Comment: Excellent point. Modern machine architectures can have very hard to predict performance. This effect could be lessened by always running pairs of programs as a bracket competition. That way absolute performance isn't as important and you still end up with good relative rankings.

Answer (score 0):

As [The Computer Language Benchmarks Game measures both CPU time and Elapsed time](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/help.php#measure) those measurements **are made sequentially in an idle environment**.